# A semi-generalization of the 2nd Borel-Cantelli lemma from Billingsley

Tags: probability

I'm trying to prep for the PhD probability qual and I'm working through Billingsley. I've been struggling with question 4.11(b)/4.14(b) depending on your edition of the book:

If for each k the series $\sum_{n>k}P(A_{n}|\cap_{i=k}^{n-1}A_{i}^{c})$ diverges then $P(\limsup A_{n})=1$.

My solution thus far:

I didn't get very far at all trying to prove the claim directly, so I'm approaching the problem by contraposition. Assuming that $P(\limsup A_{n})<1$ we must have that there exists some k s.t. $P(\cup_{i=k}^{\infty}A_{n})<1$. Therefore, we have that there exists some number b with $P(\cup_{i=k}^{\infty}A_{n})<b\leq1$.

Next, I noted that

\begin{equation}
\sum_{n>k}P(A_{n}|\cap_{i=k}^{n-1}A_{i}^{c})=\sum_{n>k}\frac{P(A_{n}\cap_{i=k}^{n-1}A_{i}^{c})}{P(\cap_{i=k}^{n-1}A_{i}^{c})}=\sum_{n>k}\frac{P(A_{n}\cap_{i=k}^{n-1}A_{i}^{c})}{1-P(\cup_{i=k}^{n-1}A_{i})}
\end{equation}

Combining my bound with the above gives us that,

\begin{equation}
\frac{1}{1-b}\sum_{n>k}P(A_{n}\cap_{i=k}^{n-1}A_{i}^{c})\geq\sum_{n>k}\frac{P(A_{n}\cap_{i=k}^{n-1}A_{i}^{c})}{1-P(\cup_{i=k}^{n-1}A_{i})}\geq\sum_{n>k}P(A_{n}\cap_{i=k}^{n-1}A_{i}^{c})
\end{equation}

Obviously, this tells us that $\sum_{n>k}P(A_{n}|\cap_{i=k}^{n-1}A_{i}^{c})$ converges iif $\sum_{n>k}P(A_{n}\cap_{i=k}^{n-1}A_{i}^{c})$ converges. Hence, I've been trying to prove the convergence of $\sum_{n>k}P(A_{n}\cap_{i=k}^{n-1}A_{i}^{c})$. Unfortunately, this effort has yet to bear fruit.

Comment: [Same problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1135316/show-that-p-limsup-a-n-1-if-for-each-k-the-series-sum-nk-pa-na-kc/1733781#1733781)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it.

It's an almost immediate consequence of the probability chain rule and the inequality $1-x\leq e^{-x}$ on $[0,1]$:
\begin{equation}
P(\cap_{i=k}^{n}A_{i}^{c})=\prod_{i=k}^{n}P(A_{i}^{c}|\cap_{i=k}^{i-1}A_{i}^{c})=\prod_{i=k}^{n}[1-P(A_{i}|\cap_{i=k}^{i-1}A_{i}^{c})]\leq e^{-\sum_{i=k}^{n}P(A_{i}|\cap_{i=k}^{i-1}A_{i}^{c})}\rightarrow0
\end{equation}

Therefore, $P(\cap_{i=k}^{\infty}A_{i}^{c})=0$ and
\begin{equation}
P(liminfA_{i}^{c})=P(\cup_{i=1}^{\infty}\cap_{j=i}^{\infty}A_{i}^{c})\leq\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}P(\cap_{i=k}^{\infty}A_{i}^{c})=0
\end{equation}