# Show that $P(\limsup A_n)=1$ if for each $k$ the series $\sum_{n>k} P(A_n|A_k^c ..A_{n-1}^c )$ diverges

Tags: probability, measure-theory, probability-theory

Show that $P(\limsup A_n)=1$ if for each $k$ the series $\sum_{n>k} P(A_n|A_k^c ..A_{n-1}^c )$ diverges.

Can we say that the second Borel-Cantelli lemma follows directly from this?

Comment: Or do you mean that it follows from the second Borel-Cantelli lemma? That would require $P(A_n|A^c_k....A^c_{n-1})=P(A_n)$

Comment: Hint: Write out the event $\lim sup A_n$ using set notation, then apply De Morgan's law and then apply the assumption.

Answer (score 2):

This problem is from Billingsley's Probability and Measure. Here comes my solution.

If $\mathbb{P}[\bigcap_{n\geq k}A_n^c]=0 \ \forall k$ then $\mathbb{P}[\liminf A_n^c]=0$ and we are done because $$\mathbb{P}[\limsup A_n]=1-\mathbb{P}[\liminf A_n^c]=1$$

So we can suppose that there exists $k$ such that $\mathbb{P}[\bigcap_{n\geq k}A_n^c]=\varepsilon > 0$, hence $\mathbb{P}[A_k^c\cap \dots\cap A_{n-1}^c]\geq \varepsilon \ \forall n$ and then we have

$$\sum_{n\geq k} \mathbb{P}[A_n\mid A_k^c\cap \dots \cap A_n^c]=\sum_{n\geq k} \frac{\mathbb{P}[A_n\cap A_k^c\cap \dots \cap A_n^c]}{\mathbb{P}[A_k^c\cap \dots \cap A_n^c]}\leq \varepsilon^{-1} \sum_{n\geq k} \mathbb{P}[A_n\cap A_k^c\cap \dots \cap A_n^c]$$
$$=\varepsilon^{-1}\sum_{n\geq k} \mathbb{P}[A_n \setminus (A_k \cup \dots \cup A_n)]= \varepsilon^{-1}\mathbb{P}[\bigcup_{n\geq k} A_n \setminus (A_k \cup \dots \cup A_n)]= \varepsilon^{-1}\mathbb{P}[\bigcup_{n\geq k} A_n]\leq \varepsilon^{-1}$$

but this is absurd $\blacksquare$